# type-graphql entities how to omit fields from JSON.stringify?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo-server

We are using https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql to define our graphql schema When we serialize the raw typescript entity object this doesn't respect the various field annotations in our GQL entities and ends up leaking unwanted data. Example below a Profile entity class

```
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from 'type-graphql'
import { Column, Entity, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from 'typeorm'
import { Account } from '../account/account.entity'

export class Profile {
  @Field()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  public username: string

  @Field()
  @Column()
  public name: string

  // Relations

  @Column()
  public accountId: string

  @ManyToOne(type => Account, account => account.profiles, { eager: true })
  public account: Account
}
```

`account` has sensitive data. When we `JSON.stringify` a Profile reference we don't want account  output. Account is not annotated with `@Field` and we expect it would not be output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decorators used by `type-graphql` only exist to instruct `type-graphql` how to translate your class to a GraphQL type -- they are not going to somehow impact how an instance of the class is serialized by a native function like `JSON.stringify`.

In the context of your schema, the `account` won't ever be returned in the response unless you explicitly create a field for it, even if the `Profile` instance used by your resolvers has that property. This is a symptom of how field resolution works in GraphQL.js. However, a `Profile` instance will always have an `account` property on it because that's what you've defined as part of your class.

It's unclear from your question why you're calling `stringify` in the first place, but assuming it's to use in some other context, like logging, then you'll want to expose your own method for serializing the instance that limits which properties are returned. This can be done easily using something like `lodash`'s `pick` or `omit`.

```
serialize () {
  return _.omit(this, ['account'])
}
```